# WooCommerce fresh install PHP errors when adding template files to theme

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I'm getting errors when trying to add WooCommerce's template files to my theme.

I download the template file and add it to a folder named woocommerce in my theme. Some templates work, such as `content-product.php` but others that aren't using just hooks seem to fail.

For example, `archive-product.php` produces the following error:

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wc_get_loop_prop() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/1/wp-content/themes/test/woocommerce/archive-product.php:65`

It's happening in the theme I'm working on, so I did a fresh install of WordPress and WooCommerce without installing anything else. I made the woocommerce directory in all the themes that come installed with WooCommerce and all produced the same error.

I also tried it with Storefront and an Underscores starter theme. When I rename the template file so it's not being used the error disappears.

I have no idea why this is happening and I can't find anything online to help. No one has had a similar problem apart from one guy who got an answer to look at their PHP version. Mine is 7.1.6, and I'm doing all this on my local machine with MAMP 4.2.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured out where I was going wrong.

Download template files that are linked to from https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/ if you are using the plugin downloaded from WordPress.org.

Don't go straight on to the GitHub repository, like I was, and download the templates. These are for the Beta development releases.

This was a stupid mistake because it says this on their Github readme...